# How to call a function directly in a Component in React Native

Tags: react-native

I made a CameraComponent.js having function **launchCamera()**. I am calling CameraComponent.js in my BottamTab navigation. I had make simple button to launch camera by calling  **launchCamera()**. But i want to launch camera directly when component call in BottamTab navigation just like in whatsapp moving topTab to left. I tried to call function in constructor instead of ComponentWillMount(as it is removed in react native). But nothing work. Here is my below code

```
export default class CameraComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        launchCamera();
        this.state = {
            filePath: {},
        };
    }
        launchCamera = () => {
        let options = {
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images',
            },
        };
            ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, response => {
            // console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            } else {
                let source = response;
                // You can also display the image using data:
                // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
                this.setState({
                    filePath: source,
                });
            }
        });
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.launchCamera.bind(this)} >
                        <Text>Launch Camera</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Call the function in componentDidMount() {this.launchCamera()}

Comment: this work, it is launching camera directly but only at the start of the app. when i reopen the camera they did not lauch camera but instead of while component.

Comment: is there a way i can launch camera evrytime when i call a component

Comment: if u are using react navigation v4 in component did mount add navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => this.launchCamera())

Comment: for v5 navigation.addListener('focus', () => this.launchCamera())